# Filter domain in people picker for SharePoint 2010 trusted domain

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, active-directory, people-picker, domain, trusted-domain

Our customer is **using 3 domains in two way trusted mode**. We are supporting applications on SharePoint 2010 Foundation.

We are facing duplicate user account issue as a few users are present in two domains and a few are present in all three.

- Lets say domains are A, B and C. SharePoint is hosted in Domain B. Users are from Domain A.
- Now I want the people picker field should show users from Domain A.
- This is required in SharePoint foundation 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I have not done this myself, but it should be do-able for SharePoint Foundation 2010 using Stsadm. The fuzz when configuring the people picker is that it's done on a site collection level basis.

The example from the blog below suggest to configure the people pickers used in a site collection to a specific domain like this:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadcustomquery -pv 
“(canonicalName=[YOURDOMAIN]*)” -url http://[yoursharepointsitecollection]
```

[Restricting the People Picker to searching one domain](http://blog.ithinksharepoint.com/2008/10/30/restricting-the-people-picker-to-searching-one-domain/)

[Configure People Picker (SharePoint Foundation 2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602066(v=office.14).aspx)